# Firefox not recognizing custom font

Tags: css, firefox, font-family, custom-font

I am using the following CSS to define a custom font on a webpage:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:zapfino;
    src:url("zapfino.ttf");
}
```

Next, I am defining an id that uses it:

```
#custom_font
{
    font-family:zapfino;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

I've tested the page on Safari and Chrome and it works fine. However, in firefox the font is not showing up, it is reverting to a default. Sorry if this is a repost but I have searched on StackOverflow and cannot find the answer! Does anyone know why this is happening? see it here: www.moosecodes.com (its still under construction! please pardon the mess!)

Comment: I do believe the name should be in quotes. Try changing the font-family declaration to "Zapfino" on both the @ font-face declaration and when defining font-family on the elements. Also, you should check the license of your Zapfino font. As it is a commercial font, it may not be licensed for use with @ font-face.

Comment: @jlego I changed all occurrences of font-family:zapfino; to the following: font-family:"zapfino"; and it didnt change anything.

Comment: SEE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface

Comment: @jiego although it's strongly recommended to put font names in quotes, it's only really necessary is when the font name contains commas, quotes or 2 or more spaces in a row, or when the font name is a keyword like "serif". See [W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-family-prop).

Comment: @everyone okay, i think i got it. whats appears is happening is that the Zapfino font is not licensed under font-family. It shows up on Chrome and safari, probably because they are both using similar technologies. It does not show up on IE9 or firefox (tested in Adobe BrowserLab). I obtained a different font (Vianta) from fontstock.com and it works in firefox. Im thinking that i'll continue to use zapfino, and override the css for IE and firefox to display a similar font. anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @MrLister Each browser supports a different type of webfont yes, but you can allow it to display in all browser by having 4 different font files for the same font and defining them in CSS. (There are still some display issues, but it works.) Also, I know about the quotes, but I like to promote best practices. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jlego is right - you should check out the [FontSquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/) site - they have an excellent tool for building your kit and converting your files for you, AND you must **always** be sure that the font is legal to use on your site.

**However** Firefox and Chrome should both support TTF, which is the format you are using.

In researching your problem on your site, what I've found is that the font is not rendering properly in **any** browser I check in.  What I've found is while the stylesheet is referencing the right file location, but the font file appears to be corrupted.  I would suggest getting a new font file new replace the one you are using.

Comment: i will go with this approach since it seems to be the fastest way to fix the problem. I think your right about the corrupt file... how did you check that? I am going to play it safe and find a font that is free to use and looks good.. that way i wont have to add any more unnecessary and messy hacks to my code... and i wont have to worry about copyright issues.. by the way, the font is owned by Apple... i think...

Comment: I downloaded the file to my computer, and when I acted as though I was going to install it, Windows tells me it's corrupted.

Answer (score 4):

Each browser only reads one file type for webfonts. Unfortunately, they are all different file formats. In order for the font to display correctly in all browsers, you will need 4 different types of font file- TTF, WOFF, SVG & EOT. Your code will look something like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Zapfino';
    src: url('Zapfino.eot');
    src: url('Zapfino.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Zapfino.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Zapfino.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Zapfino.svg#SansumiRegular') format('svg');
}
```

That code is based of the stylesheet included with [FontSquirell](http://www.fontsquirell.com) fonts.

FontSquirell has a converter, but you do need to check your license. Zapfino is a commercial font owned by Adobe(?) and as far as I know using their fonts with @font-face is a violation of the fonts EULAs.

[TypeKit](https://typekit.com/) offers commercial fonts for use with @font-face for a fee that complies with the foundries EULAs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.... the answer by jlego was usefull to me.
My font was recognized in Chrome and IE.
In FF my TTF wasn't recognized untill I added the format('truetype') in my css file.